# Need regular expression logic

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector a as follows:

```
a <- c("Rs. 360 Rs. 540 [-33% ]", "Rs. 213 Rs. 250 [-15% ]", "Rs. 430 Rs. 1030 [-58% ]")
```

Need answer as below:

a should have `Rs.360, Rs.213, Rs.430`

I have used:

```
a <- gsub(" Rs*", "", a)
```

Comment: `substr(a, 1, 7)` or to get rid of the space `gsub("^(Rs.) (\\d{3}).+", "\\1\\2", a)`

Comment: Is `Rs.` always a fixed string at the start? Are there always 3 digit numbers after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex with capturing groups that will grab the parts you need and using backreferences in the replacement pattern you may insert them back into the result:

```
sub("^\\s*(Rs\\.)\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", a)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wKJO9M/2)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `\\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(Rs\\.)` - Group 1 capturing `Rs.` sequence
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\\d+)`  - Group 2 caprturing 1 or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string to its end

Tested code:

```
> a <- c("Rs. 360 Rs. 540 [-33% ]", "Rs. 213 Rs. 250 [-15% ]", "Rs. 430 Rs. 1030 [-58% ]")
> sub("^\\s*(Rs\\.)\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", a)
[1] "Rs.360" "Rs.213" "Rs.430"
```

**Update**

For an input like `a <- c(" 360 540", " 213 250")`, use `sub("^\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", a)`.

```
> a <- c(" 360 540", " 213 250")
> sub("^\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", a)
[1] "360" "213"
```

The `^\\D*(\\d+).*` matches any amount of non-digit symbols at the start of the string, then captures 1+ digits into Group 1, and then `.*` matches the rest of the string.

Comment: this didnot work for me as there was  extra space at the start..i have removed other things..now the vector looks like a <- (" 360 540", " 213 250")..i need 360 and 213...note there is space before 360 and 213(i.e at start)..so need to drop everything after second white space..

Comment: So, `Rs.` is optional? I modified the initial suggestion and added a solution for the new strings you provided in the comment above.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in comment, you can use `substr` to extract the beginning of the string, if you always have the same pattern (same number of digits). You can further suppress the space if you want to:

```
substr(a, 1, 7)
[1] "Rs. 360" "Rs. 213" "Rs. 430"
sub(" ", "", substr(a, 1, 7))
[1] "Rs.360" "Rs.213" "Rs.430"
```

Or you can capture the pattern you want in the string and form another string with just that:

```
gsub("^[A-Za-z.]{3} (\\d{3}).+", "Rs.\\1", a)
[1] "Rs.360" "Rs.213" "Rs.430"
```

Here you're capturing only the 3 digits and putting explicitly back the `Rs.`.

Or you can "erase" everything that you don't want : the space and everything that comes after the pattern you want to keep:

```
gsub("(\\s)|([A-Za-z0-9. ]{8}\\s\\[-*\\d+%\\s*\\])", "", a)
[1] "Rs.360" "Rs.213" "Rs.430"
```

Here, you specify you want to suppress the space (`\\s`) and/or 8 characters that are either alphanumeric or a dot or a space, followed by a space, an opening bracket, nothing or a minus sign, more than one digit(s), a % sign, nothing or a space and finally a closing bracket.